# How can I redirect a user to Django auth from a webpage not a part of the Django app?

Tags: django, web-deployment, server-side, django-authentication

We have a R shiny app server to whose links will be present on our Django website. However we want the user to be taken to login(and check if they have the permission to access) before they are able to access the R shiny app page.
We could embed the Shiny app using an iframe on our site, but then anybody can copy the src link and use it to access shiny app without login, later.

Comment: Good question. Even I'm looking for a solution like this. Hope someone from the Django or R community could answer this. There seems to be one possibility here: https://paolo-cozzi.medium.com/managing-shiny-authentication-with-django-1d3b307e8c73